# Variable length array with unknown size

Tags: c, arrays

In C, because of the framework I use and generate though a compiler, I am required to use global variable length array.
However, I can not know the size of its dimension until runtime (though `argv` for example).
For this reason, I would like to declare a global variable length array with unknown size and then define its size.

I have done it like that :

```
int (*a)[]; //global variable length array
int main(){
  //defining it's size
  a = (int(*)[2]) malloc(sizeof(int)*2*2);

  for(int i=0;i<2; i++){
      for(int j=0;j<2; j++){
          a[i][j] = i*2 + j;
      }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

However, this does not work : I get the `invalid use of array with unspecified bounds` error. I suspect it is because even if its size is defined, its original type does not define the size of the larger stride.

Does someone know how to solve this issue ? Using C99 (no C++) and it should be quite standard (working on gcc and icc at least).

EDIT: I may have forget something that matters. I am required to propose an array that is usable through the "static array interface", I mean by that the multiple square bracket (one per dimension).

Comment: If you're going to `malloc` it anyway, what's the point of the VLA? Just use a pointer.

Comment: @DeiDei the VLA is for the second dimension. It is a two dimensional array.

Comment: You *cannot* do what you need, use an array of pointers if this is absolutely necessary.

Comment: You cannot use a variably-modified type (a VLA) for a variable defined at file scope, nor in a structure or union, or ...  You are not allowed to do what you are trying to do.  You will have to go with a simple pointer and a length, maybe in a structure: `int *a = 0; int a_size = 0;` and then assign values appropriately.  (Or an array of pointers — `int **a = 0;`)

Comment: You can declare a `void*` and a `size` variable though and then cast the `void*` to an appropriate size VLA every time you have to use.

Comment: you can't use unspecified length if size doesn't know you should use pointer if 2D data then `int **a`

Comment: @ThiruShetty `int**` and `int[][]` are completely different...

@AjayBrahmakshatriya this issue here, is that it does not allow me to access a value using the multiple bracket operator, and I am required to do so :(

@DeiDei Well, tell me how I can acces an array value using multiple bracket with a single pointer...

Comment: @Viridya you can't declare array of unknown length at compile time. you can achieve either by argument pass means `argv` but that will be inside main. If you want global you should use pointer or know length of array.

Comment: See [C11 §6.7.6.2 Array declarators ¶2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.2p2) and nearby text (¶4 and ¶5, for example).

Comment: Don't use global variables in the first place, and all your problems will go away.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks I check that.

Comment: @Lundin it's quite easy to spot people who clearly never programmed more than a Celcius/Farhenheit convertor :)

Comment: To continue the thought of @Lundin. Having a global array is usually really a bad idea and it would be much better if you'd pass your (pointer to) VLA as argument to your functions. *There* the use of such beasts is possible if you pass along the lengths of the dimensions before the VLA.

Comment: @JensGustedt what you don't seem to understand is that I am required to use global fixed array to use a specific library AND I am required to not fix the length of the array at compile time, resulting in "I am required to use global VLA". Yes this is stupid, yes if I could use malloc or local VLA I would do so, but no I can't.

Comment: @Viridya, then you are really a the limits of the model. The reason that VLA and derivatives are not allowed as globals is that in addition to the array itself they have hidden state, namely the length of the dimensions. This hidden state cannot be exposed easily across different translation units if you want to be backwards compatible to other handling of C arrays on a ABI level. Basically, a function can never now if what it receives originated as VLA or not. This could, in principle, still work if your VLA would be `static`, but that was not the path that was chosen by the committee.

Answer (score 2):

First `a` is not an array but a pointer to an array of unspecified length. What you are trying to do is not possible. You can't have a global variable length array.
But with the present scenario you can use this to access the memory allocated to `a`

```
for(int i=0;i<2; i++){
    int *ptr = *a + 2*i;
    for(int j=0;j<2; j++){
        ptr[j] = i*2 + j;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, sorry for the terminology. Hum, this is not possible according to the standard ?

Comment: @Viridya; Yes. It's not possible as per C standard.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare a global *multi dimensional* VLA, because even if you use pointers, all the dimensions except for the first one must be known at declaration time.

My best attempt would be to use a global `void *`. In C `void *` is a special pointer type that can be used to store a pointer to any type, and is often used for *opaque* pointers.

Here you could do:

```
void *a; // opaque (global variable length array) pointer 
int main() {
    //defining it's size
    a =  malloc(sizeof(int) * 2 * 2);  // the global opaque pointer
    int(*a22)[2] = a;                  // a local pointer to correct type
    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<2; j++) {
            a22[i][j] = i * 2 + j;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When you need to access the *global VLA*, you assign the value of the opaque global to a local VLA pointer, and can then use it normally. You will probably have to store the dimensions in global variables too...

Comment: `int(*a22)[2]` is a pointer to a **fixed** size array, not VLA!